# Javascript math form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, math, input-field

I'm building a form with some javascript math functions and can't seem to get the 3rd field to work as I want

- When you enter **100** in the blue price box field 'How much would you like to be paid for selling this bottle'
- Then 25 is put into the next field which is correct.
- but the SELL PRICE INCLUDING TAX field isn't working, It should take 100 then add the next field so in this case 125 then multiply it by 1.125. To give the answer $140.63

https://www.cloudwine.com.au/list-private-wine

---

FORM FIELDS

```
<label for="CAT_Custom_15"><b>How much would you like to be paid for selling this bottle?</b></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" onchange="output()" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15" class="cat_textbox price bborder" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_14">Cloudwine Commission 25%</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_14" id="CAT_Custom_14" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_13">SELL PRICE INCLUDING TAX</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_13" id="CAT_Custom_13" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />
```

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
function output(){

    var startPriceV2 = jQuery( "#CAT_Custom_15" ).val();

    jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_14' ).val( parseInt(startPriceV2) * (0.25) ).toFixed(2);

    var cloudCom = jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_14' ).val();            

    jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_13' ).val( parseInt(startPriceV2) + parseInt(cloudCom) * (1.125) ).toFixed(2);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean maxlength="4000" ?

Comment: That's a field default. 4000 chacters

Comment: Clearly, it is. But you don't want to use 4000 characters to write a computed value, do you? I feel this sort of property adds 'noise' to your code and suggest you discard it.

Comment: See my proper answer. Hope you will find it useful…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toFixed()` is on a `jQuery` element, not on the number value.

Also, `toFixed()` returns a String, I used the `+` operator to convert it to a number.

I've stored the calculations in variables instead of fetching them from your page again. This improves performance by reducing jQuery calls..

Change the JS to this:

```js
function output(){
                 
  var startPriceV2 = +jQuery( "#CAT_Custom_15" ).val();
  var tax = +(startPriceV2 * (0.25)).toFixed(2);
  var cloudCom = +((startPriceV2 + tax) * 1.125).toFixed(2);      

  jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_14' ).val( tax );  
  jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_13' ).val( cloudCom );

}
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="CAT_Custom_15"><b>How much would you like to be paid for selling this bottle?</b></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" onchange="output()" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15" class="cat_textbox price bborder" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_14">Cloudwine Commission 25%</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_14" id="CAT_Custom_14" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_13">SELL PRICE INCLUDING TAX</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_13" id="CAT_Custom_13" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />
```

---

You can also do this without jQuery, which is preferred by many developers.

```js
function output(){   

  var priceInput = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_15');
  var commisionInput = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_14');
  var totalInput = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_13');
                 
  var startPriceV2 = +priceInput.value;
  var commision = +(startPriceV2 * (0.25)).toFixed(2);
  var cloudCom = +((startPriceV2 + commision) * 1.125).toFixed(2);   
  
  commisionInput.value = commision;
  totalInput.value = cloudCom;

}
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label for="CAT_Custom_15"><b>How much would you like to be paid for selling this bottle?</b></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" onchange="output()" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15" class="cat_textbox price bborder" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_14">Cloudwine Commission 25%</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_14" id="CAT_Custom_14" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="CAT_Custom_13">SELL PRICE INCLUDING TAX</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_13" id="CAT_Custom_13" class="cat_textbox price" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: There is also an additional error in the second calculation. Op wants to apply the tax to price PLUS comission, so `parseInt(startPriceV2) + parseInt(cloudCom) * (1.125)` should be `(parseInt(startPriceV2) + parseInt(cloudCom)) * (1.125)` instead. This way the outcome is $140.63, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
function output(){

  var startPriceV2 = jQuery( "#CAT_Custom_15" ).val();

    jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_14' ).val( (parseInt(startPriceV2) * (0.25)).toFixed(2) );

    var cloudCom = jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_14' ).val();            

    jQuery( '#CAT_Custom_13' ).val( (parseInt(startPriceV2) + parseInt(cloudCom) * (1.125)).toFixed(2) );

}
```

You messed up your `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: thanks, but it wasn't adding the Commission to including tax field

Comment: @Jake — Very true. Refer to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Number-rounding is only peripheral (and pointless) for your so far. Your case is one of right architecture and good practices, e.g. not using input fields for computed field and not attaching event-handlers from inside your html code: using jQuery would be quite appropriate too to attach handlers.

I have also found out that the 'onchange' event handler does not yield the expected result, hence my changing it for 'onblur'. I cannot explain why but I shall not dig further into it, for attaching handlers from within html is definitely deprecated.

As for a development and practising pattern, try this —a 'noiseless' snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #commission {
            width: 60px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        #finalPrice {
            width: 60px;
            height: 20px;
            color: white;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    How Much? <input type="text" onblur="output();" id="price">
    <br>
    Cloudwine comm.: <div id="commission"></div>
    Price: <div id="finalPrice"></div>


    <script>
        function output ()
        {
            let priceValue = Number ($('#price').val()),
                resultCommission = Number (priceValue *.25),
                firstAddition = priceValue + resultCommission,
                resultFinal = firstAddition + firstAddition *.125 ;

            $('#commission').html (resultCommission);
            $('#finalPrice').html (resultFinal);
        }
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I surmise you turned to those input fields because of formatting. Do not do so, use CSS instead (and particularly to 'float' rules).

Also, I have explicity coerced values to Number: JS being a very lax language you can get strange outcomes if you do not pay attention.